# content placeholder problem asp/css/html

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

hey guys something is going wrong with my content placeholder:

[image]

My stuff is outside of the placeholder yet in my asp code its inside it:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
    <%--<div class="workout-article-table">--%>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="workout-article-table" runat="server"> <%--takes place of div--%>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass="workout-article-table-column" runat="server"> <%--takes place of span--%>
    <%--<span class="workout-article-table-column">--%>

    <div class="workout-article-table-blue">
        <div class="workout-article-table-title">beginner workout programs »</div>
    </div>
    <div class="workout-article-table-link-black">
        <div class="workout-article-table-link"><a href="#">Beginning Bodybuilding Comprehensive Guide</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="workout-article-table-link-gray">
        <div class="workout-article-table-link"><a href="#">Resistance-Training For Total Beginners!</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="workout-article-table-link-black">
        <div class="workout-article-table-link"><a href="#">Best Mass-Building Workout For Beginners</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="workout-article-table-link-black">
        <div align="center"><span class="workout-blue-links"><a href="#">View All Beginner Programs »</a></span></div>
    </div>
    <%--</span>--%>
     </asp:Panel> <%--takes place of inner span--%>



    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" CssClass="workout-article-table-column2" runat="server"> <%--takes place of span--%>
    <%--<span class="workout-article-table-column2">--%>

    <div class="workout-article-table-blue">
        <div class="workout-article-table-title">intermediate workout programs »</div>
    </div>
    <div class="workout-article-table-link-black">
        <div class="workout-article-table-link"><a href="#">No Longer A Beginner</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="workout-article-table-link-gray">
        <div class="workout-article-table-link"><a href="#">You're Not A 'Newbie' Anymore!</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="workout-article-table-link-black">
        <div class="workout-article-table-link"><a href="#">Novice Intermediate Workout!</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="workout-article-table-link-black">
        <div align="center"><span class="workout-blue-links"><a href="#">View More Workout Programs »</a></span></div>
    </div>

    <%--</span>--%>
    </asp:Panel> <%--takes the place of inner span--%>
    </asp:Panel> <%--takes the place of div--%>
</asp:Content>
```

**CSS:**

```
.workout-article-table {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 483pxpx
}
.workout-article-table-column {
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 229px
}
.workout-article-table-column2 {
    float: left;
    left: 254px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 229px
}
.workout-article-table-blue {
    background-color: #0F709B;
    height: 40px;
    width: 229px
}
.workout-article-table-blue-wide {
    background-color: #0F709B;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 483px
}
.workout-article-table-link-black {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 40px;
    width: 229px
}
.workout-article-table-link-gray {
    background-color: #27282A;
    height: 40px;
    width: 229px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok I fixed it Panel 1 underneath wasn't spacing along with the other panels I had to do it manually as it was a copy and paste.